# populating inner attribute within sub object in mongoose document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a following type of schema and I want populate the guide details when getting a tour document. I tried with Tour.findById(id).populate({path: 'summary.guide'}). But in the result it returns a null for guide. How to populate that guide details?

```
const tourSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     from: String,
     to: String,
     summary: {
         guide: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
         duration: Number,
         distance: Number
     }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you should not pass the `user id` into the `summary.guide` object.
2. The second possibility is `user id` and `summary.guide` not match.
3. The third possibility is `summary.guide` is not exist.

this code works for me

```
Tour.findById("5dcd2c61...").populate({path: 'summary.guide'});
```

Comment: can you send me your query.?